# Document.body doesn't exist. Modernizr hyphens test needs it

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I wish I could explain what's causing this issue. I've searched and simply have no idea. When  I move this Foundations, Red, etc. framework between projects it tends to follow. Any advice would be useful.

http://goo.gl/HbTUL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading your customized Modernizr lib (with Hyphenator, which is causing the problem) in `<head>`, at a moment where `<body>` doesn't exist yet, hence the error.

An obvious solution would be to move the loading of the Modernizr lib to the bottom of your page (in or after `<body>`), although [this](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing) suggests that doing that might cause some issues. If it does, try separating Hyphenator from the Modernizr lib and load it separately.