# IE7, IE8, IE9 support for Laravel application with Bootstrap for "placeholder"

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, placeholder

I've built a Laravel 4.2 app [Sputnikart](http://sputnikart.net)

with Bootstrap v3.2.0 and am using this website as part of my portfolio, I discovered recently that over 50% of people going to my website and possibly accessing this site are using IE7 to IE9, and while it works perfectly on other browsers, everything goes haywire on IE8.

I've spent over a day researching and trying different approaches to many problems (added html5shiv.js & respond.js) to fix the menu collapsing and becoming unworkable and tried using Mathias Bynens (placeholder.js) file to fix the placeholders not being visible, however as soon as I did this my app stopped authenticating in properly so that even I couldn't log in.

I have the usual declarations on my master.blade

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> ...
```

I am really posting this to see if anyone can help with good pointers and resources in coping with a Laravel 4.2 app with Bootstrap for IE7 to IE9, the problems are too numerous to mention

thankx

conditional comments...
    .ie6 .ie7 .ie8 .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
      _color: thistle;
      *color:thistle;
      color:thistle\9;
    }

Comment: post this in a fiddle or something. it looks like you have an open comment after the gt IE 8 conditional comment

Comment: @albert site is up live and functioning properly on most browsers, head code can be seen with inspector

Comment: yeah i bet you its that comment http://validator.w3.org/nu/?useragent=Validator.nu%2FLV+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fsputnikart.net%2Findex.php%2F

Comment: @albert you were right, i've fixed it but it hasn't solved my problems with the placehoders - thankyou anyway

Comment: what properties are declared in ie8 when you inspect it? sorry i don't have an install and can't get a good vm on this machine. i bet this is something easily solvable with conditional comments

Comment: @albert i have declared conditional comments such as shown above also have put jquery back to v 1.11.3

Comment: error i am getting when i run debugging is referenced here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583390/document-body-doesnt-exist-modernizr-hyphens-test-needs-it but as the post suggests moving modernizer down to the bottom  of the page causes even more problems

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar trouble with an laravel 4.2 app compatability with IE8.
My site is sirai.gim.med.up.pt/index.php/ram/create

It is working fine with all browsers except with IE8 and lower versions.
I dont have declarations in my main.blade, should I?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{trans('views.title')}}</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {{HTML::style('css/main.css')}}
 
    {{HTML::style('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
    {{HTML::style('css/datepicker3.css')}}
     {{HTML::style('css/bootstrap-table.css')}}
 
</head>
```

Tested the blade that does not work in here, as you two did http://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fsirai.gim.med.up.pt%2Findex.php%2Fram%2Fcreate

Would be thankfull for some support :)

Its my very first time posting in Stack Overflow as a registered user, sorry if i fail to see some solution in the answers above .

Answer (score 0):

@Toni_Manshengo

to the head add what I have listed as code in my question

also you need to add the following files to your application and above the closing  tag (jquery version must not be higher than shown as the later versions are not compatible with older IE browsers

```
@section ('scripts')
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/placeholder.min.js') }}
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You will also need to add some additional styling to the css file for IE7, IE8, IE9 equivalent to

```
/* support for IE6/7 uses media, */
@media, { 
.form-control::-moz-placeholder .ie6 .ie7 { color: thistle; } 
}
/* support for IE8 uses \0 */
@media all\0 { 
.form-control::-moz-placeholder .ie8 { color: thistle; } 
} 
/* support for IE9 uses \9  targets IE8 and bellow */
@media all and (monochrome:0) { 
.form-control::-moz-placeholder .ie8 .ie9 { color: thistle\9; }
} 
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #999999;
}
/* support for IE6/7 uses media, */
@media, { 
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder .ie6 .ie7{ color: thistle; } 
}
/* support for IE8 uses \0 */
@media all\0 { 
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder .ie8 { color: thistle; } 
} 
/* support for IE9 uses \9  targets IE8 and bellow */
@media all and (monochrome:0) { 
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder .ie8 .ie9 { color: thistle\9; }
} 
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #999999;
}
/* support for IE6/7 uses media, */
@media, { 
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder .ie6 .ie7 { color: thistle; } 
}
/* support for IE8 uses \0 */
@media all\0 { 
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder .ie8 { color: thistle; } 
} 
/* support for IE9 uses \9  targets IE8 and bellow */
@media all and (monochrome:0) { 
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder .ie8 .ie9 { color: thistle\9; }
}
```

hope this helps you and other people out in areas where there are still lots of IE8 users, it's taken me a long time to figure it out 
zod